# How to sync 2 git repositories on 2 different account?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a situation that I have a main git repository in one bitbucket account and another repository into another account. One is the repository that we use daily and the other is the client repository that I need to update on a weekly basis.
How can I do that transfering all the versions of the files? Any way to have a build on jenkins to do it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use git remote branching strategy to merge it before you start Jenkins build to have it.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Answer (score 0):

You can push the changes to the second repo but using diff remote name.
Eg:
git push alias_for_repo1 branch_name
git push alias_for_repo2 branch_name